# Which way does Inheritace take place inside?

Tags: c++

- Consider a simple picture below.

[image]

```
Here Child inherit's its properties from both, Parent 1 and Parent 2, and Also the properties directly from the Grand Parent.
```

Let each be seperate class.
* Its obvious that, to avoid the `conflict of child inheriting the properties of parent 1 and parent 2, we make a base class "virtual" .`

From, where ever I've learnt I was instructed that in `main`function, In `child` class, I could get the properties of `parent` or `grandparent`.

I get confused when, I try to think what happens with 
**Compiler** and **Memory side** internally.

Let `display()` be the member function of all `Grandparent` and `parent1` and `parent2`. Now the **virtual** base class takes necessary steps, to avoid ambiguity in the `child` which actually has two duplicate sets of `parent1` and `parent2`, yes also the `grandparent`.

Now, I want to make myself clear that

- If the `display()` of the `grandparent` is accessed from the `child` using *pointer* and *addresses* internally. `child` won't be having the any duplicate sets. So, there won't araise any ambiguity therefore why else are we going for `virtual` funtions?
- In other case, What I'm thinking above is wrong, and consider that `display()` of `grandparent` is actually or *I assume to be* copied into the `child`,and the same should happen with the `parent1 and parent2`. (Please, don't say that base `child` will be having access or containing public and protected members of `grandparent, parent1 and parent2` , I'm sorry, the reason is that, this is the answer I found on *Internet* and it doesn't clarify me, when I think how I happens) As a result, child should be having same member function in the same class of `child`, this should definitely give problems because child couldn't have same member functions as even `constructors` differ in `arguments`.
- Any other cases are possible, please explain.

I made my maximum effort to detail my doubt.
If possible, help me to understand how exactly the virtual classes and inheritance concepts work.

Thank you.

--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An object of a derived type contains within it a subobject of the base type. When you call a non-virtual, non-static member function of the base class, then that function is effectively invoked on that base subobject.

(Note that it is possible to have multiple base subobjects of the same type when you use multiple inheritance.)

Virtual functions behave somewhat differently: a virtual call always requests a (usually dynamic) search for the most-derived object of which the invoked object is a base subobject, and then call the last overrider of the function. But that's essentially unrelated to the point of the question. For example, when you have `struct A { virtual void f(); }; struct B : A {};` and then call `B().f()`, that call is still performed on the `A`-subobject – the virtual dispatch only starts there.

Answer (score 1):

A derived class is composed of everything that the base class is PLUS your extra bits. No copying takes place because a class is just like a design. It's the *object* where stuff actually exists. When you *instantiate* the derived class (create an object of it) it will contain members of the derived and base class as one.

Your class is like a blueprint - the design for a house. I could design a house with 1 bedroom, 1 bathroom and a kitchen. This blueprint is like your class. I can't pee in the bathroom yet: *it's just a design on paper*. I can't make a sandwich in kitchen. Now I can choose to have the house built - this is then an **object**. Now I *can* take a pee. It's quite a relief, I had to wait ages. In fact I can make as many copies of this house as I like. Making copies is **instantiating more objects**.

But one day I think to myself I'd like a bigger house *based on this one* so I make a new design that I can simply add to the old design extending the house. **This is inheritance**. My new design has a lounge added on and another toilet (I need to pee a lot, ok?). When I *instantiate* this version of my design I'll get a house which contains a bedroom from the 1st design, and bathroom, and kitchen as well as my lounge.

Sounds to me like you need to get a good book on object oriented programming. It won't be as amazing as my explanation there, no doubt, and probably won't talk about toilets as much as one would normally like, however it will explain much more than this. Good luck.

Comment: What is the meaning of _it will contain members of derived and base class as one_ ? 
Does **compiler** goes to base class, to access the member function called from a derived class or what ? :)

Comment: What a compiler does is look at code, which is conceptual for our understanding, and turn it into executable machine code. Your comment here suggests you think that classes and objects are concepts known to the CPU - they are not. I will update my answer a bit too that may help you see this

Comment: Very much thanks to put your efforts to giving a good answer.
May be I'm not asking my question well. I'm sorry.
I just want to do this with an example

Comment: Good books on the subject will be full of examples! - I'm not sure what you what "an example" of. How compiler's work? Where code physically sits in memory? How to implement basic inheritance? You need to be specific. That's probably why your question has been downvoted. Just read a good book on it - find a good tutorial online. Best of luck! Enjoy :)